# 'No Session found for current thread' while handling an event

Tags: events, grails

I have an issue with obtaining a session inside event handler method.
Grails version: 3.0.11

So, the code itself:

```
class FooController {

    def notifyFoo(Long id) {
      notify('Foo:foo', id)
      sendSuccessMessage(message(code: 'Message.Text.Success'))
    }
}

@Consumer
class BarService {

    static transactional = false

    @Selector('Foo:foo')
    @Transactional
    def onFoo(Long fooId) {
        Baz baz = Baz.findByFooId(fooId)
        baz.bazProp++
        **baz.save()**   /*Here i get the error about 'No session found'*/
    }
}
```

I have tried different ways to deal with this issue:

- moving all business logic into another method that is marked as @Transactional and explicitly calling it from onFoo() method
- wrapping business logic inside onFoo() with Baz.withTransaction {}, Baz.withSession {}, Baz.withNewSession {} closures

In any case i get the same error: **org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread**

Can anyone help me with my issue? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't combine `static transactional = false` and `@Transactional` in the same service - use one or the other:

- if all service methods are not transactional use `static transactional = false`
- if all service methods require a read/write transaction use `static transactional = true`
- if different methods (of the same service) have different transactional semantics, use annotations

In Grails 3.X the static annotation is deprecated, so only annotations should be used.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. This code snippet is just an essention from my real project code. Of course there are a lot of methods in that service that should not be wrapped in transaction, that's why i am using `static transactional = false`